# COUNT DISTINCT + COUNT GROUP BY HAVING (value) + GROUP BY months

Tags: mysql

I have a table with columns: cid, date

Sample table data: Note: cid contains string values eg: 'otsytb8o7sbs50w9doghwzvfy0vb8f9h' many are duplicated.

```
 cid. date  
--------------------------------------------------------
1   2015-10-10 04:57:57
2   2015-10-10 05:03:58
3   2015-10-10 05:24:49
4   2015-10-10 05:28:24
5   2015-10-10 05:28:26
6   2015-10-10 05:28:40
7   2015-10-10 05:30:39
8   2015-10-10 05:33:04
9   2015-10-10 05:35:42
9   2015-10-10 05:36:03
```

I want to get the following:

1. Count of Distinct `cid` as uniqVisits
2. Count of `cid` HAVING (count <= 1) as bounced
3. Grouped by month

I want to get bounce rate per month from Cookie ID's (`cid`).

So I am looking for: ( COUNT of unique Cookie ID's with a count of <=1 ) for bounced, and ( COUNT DISTINCT cid's ) for total unique visitors, Grouped By month

Desired result:

```
uniqVisits | bounced | month
-----------|---------|-------
2345       | 325     | 2015-10
-----------|---------|-------
7345       | 734     | 2015-11
-----------|---------|-------
3982       | 823     | 2015-12
-----------|---------|-------
4291       | 639     | 2016-01
```

I have tried a lot of methods the below is the closest I can get but it gives me error: "Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

```
SELECT count(*) AS bounced,
( SELECT count( DISTINCT(cid) ) AS uniqVisits,
    SUBSTR(DATE(date),1,7) AS month
    FROM table ) AS uniqVisits
FROM (
   SELECT COUNT(cid) AS bounced,
   SUBSTR(DATE(date),1,7) AS month
   FROM table
   GROUP BY cid
   HAVING (count <= 1)
) AS x
GROUP BY month
```

How can I write this query to give me the desired result I want in the "Desired result:" chart / table illustrated above?

BTW: I also tried the below query but it times out, and then throws a server error: It also does not group the second query into month, obviously because of the "cid having count <=1"

```
SELECT c1.uniqVisits,
        c1.month,
        c2.bounced
    FROM ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t1.cid)    AS `uniqVisits`,
SUBSTR(DATE(t1.date),1,7) AS `month`
FROM table t1
GROUP BY month
        ) c1
    JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*)         AS `bounced`,
SUBSTR(DATE(t2.date),1,7) AS `month`
FROM table t2
GROUP BY month, cid HAVING (count <= 1)
        ) c2
    ON c2.month = c1.month
    ORDER BY c1.month
```

Comment: Just to clarify: please add the *exact* input data that would produce the *exact* output data you're looking for. There is no way to get 7345 from that input, for example.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen it is just a count, there are 100000's of values in the table, your request is not feasable. Also someone has edited out my actual values, but it is irrelevant as we are just counting the number of `cid` many of which contain duplicate data ie the same `cid` string value

Comment: @Grant It is very feasible. You already provided an input. Now provide the output you want *from that data*, not from some other data. There is no need for bazillions of rows of real data. Just *some input* and *corresponding output* that shows what you want.

Comment: This request is for US validate our attempts. There is no way we could provide you an accurate answer if we couldn't validate it. That is why you need to provide the desired output from **sample data given**

Comment: As mentioned in the question the output must equal the "Desired result:" table in my question that is what I want as output: uniqVisits = 2345, bounced = 325, month = 2015-10 per row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have resolved this:

```
SELECT uniqVisitors, COUNT(*) AS bounced, T1.month
FROM (
    SELECT cid,
    SUBSTR(DATE(date),1,7) AS month
    FROM table
    GROUP BY cid
    HAVING COUNT(*) <= 1
) T1
LEFT JOIN
( SELECT count( DISTINCT(cid) ) AS uniqVisitors,
    SUBSTR(DATE(date),1,7) AS month
    FROM table
    GROUP By month ) T2
ON T1.month = T2.month
GROUP BY month
```

Gives me:

```
uniqVisitors | bounced | month  
---------------------------------
7237    6822    2015-10
12597   12136   2015-11
12980   12573   2015-12
12091   11695   2016-01
5396    5134    2016-02
```